# Hierarchical string into PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string `a[b][c]` and I need to convert it into multidimensional PHP array. Does anybody knows a quick solution for that without using `eval()`?

Comment: Please show us your string in full and explain what you've already tried...

Comment: I literally have a string `form[auth][key]`. I need this parsed into `array("form"=>array("auth"=>array("key")))`

Comment: If it's valid PHP why don't you want to eval() it? If you want to pass data in string format why don't you serialize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found solution for that:

`parse_str("a[b][c]", $result);`

Resulted multidimensional array is written into `$result` variable.

[Source](http://codepad.org/PPT5GJUn)